# eps files by originpro can not show properly in latex

Tags: graphics, eps

I have incorporate EPS file in the LaTeX, but the series are not shown properly. As in attached picture, the right is correct (shown by evince) and the left is what it looks in PDF generated by LaTeX.
[image: print screen]

I used the following code to embed EPS in the PDF file. What is the possible reason for this? How to fix it?

```
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{figures/p1-adversaries.eps}%
 \end{center}%\vspace{-0.15in}
 \caption{XXX}\label{exp:p1_adversaries}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: Try exporting your graph in pdf or png format from origin and insert in latex file. There are other replacements for originpro like `qtiplot` (http://www.cells.es/Members/cpascual/docs/unofficial-qtiplot-packages-for-windows) and `scidavis` (http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/) that provide export facility directly in to `tikz` code (Qtiplot).

Comment: See whether `trim = num1 num2 num3 num4` option works. I use this as this example shows a lot. \includegraphics[width=3.7in, height=3.8in, clip=true, trim = 85 0 0 0]{fig.eps} This can fix most of the bounding box issues.

Comment: By the way: Don't use `{center}` but `\centering` inside `figure`s and `table`s. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651) for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution will be to export your graph in to PDF or PNG format from origin and then insert it in your LaTeX file.

Also, you may consider using [*Qtiplot*](http://www.cells.es/Members/cpascual/docs/unofficial-qtiplot-packages-for-windows) and [*scidavis*](http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/) both of which are freely available. Some of the Linux distributions have qtiplot within by default. Of these qtiplot allows you to export your graph directly into TikZ code, which one can `\input` in to the TeX file. From scidavis, you can export the graph into SVG files.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the PNG format for diagrams for this, but keep it as a vector graphic, i.e. export directly to PDF.