# Export Graphs from OriginPro with LaTeX Typesetting

Tags: fonts, graphics, incompatibility

I've looked online for an answer to my question, but I was wondering if it's possible to export graphs from OriginPro for inclusion into a LaTeX document using LaTeX typesetting? I'm using `PDFLaTeX` when compling my document.

If not, could anyone recommend a suitable alternative?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of OriginPro, but there are many ways of capturing graphs. If you have Adobe Acrobat, you can print a graph directly into a PDF, and then use Acrobat to further crop it to size. That is nicest. Barring that, you can get the graph on your screen, hit Shift-PrtScn to make a copy of the screen, and paste that image into an image manipulator like Paint Shop Pro and crop it from there. The downside to this latter approach is that the image is rasterized and will therefore suffer under zoom.  At that point, import to PDFLatex via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: OriginPro (last time I checked) has a dedicated export option to EPS, PDF and JPEG formats (no need for PDF emulated printers). So it is possible to include graphics with `latex` and `pdflatex` and the `\includegraphics` command. One word of caution is that the fonts may not be properly embedded in the PDF as the exporter seemed to be buggy (last time I checked).  I don't think this is proper TeX-related question though.

Comment: Here it is an example problematic case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52739/eps-files-by-originpro-can-not-show-properly-in-latex.

Comment: Originpo doesn't support latex exports. You may export your graph as pdf (with tight margins) and open the pdf in inkscape, export to tikz using the inkscape extension `inkscape2tikz`. You get a tikz code for your graph and fonts suit the document nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Origin, but whatever program you use, it is always worth to introduce an intermediate step as described [in a post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6387013/803359). (Hence, that's your workaround). The post is on EPS, then convert to PDF.

Comment: @Steven: There are plenty of free PDF printers, so no need for commercial Acrobat Pro. The same is true for PDF crop. Use the free [briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/). Took me a while to find that tool, but works great and is extremely small. Actually, it sets a boundingbox, which you might do by hand as well inside of LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved the issue by saving my graphs in the EPS format, opening the file in Inkscape, and saving it as a PDF with LaTeX text support (PDF help file [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf)). My document compiles correctly with LaTeX typesetting as well using `PDFLaTeX`.

It's also possible to un-group all the various parts of the EPS file in Inkscape so that LaTeX commands, math mode, etc. can be used.

P.S. I used Matlab to generate the EPS graph, haven't checked with OriginPro yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use **LM Roman 10** font in OriginPro so that the graph itself has latex default font.

All you have to do is download and add the required font to fonts folder of your pc. OriginPro will load it the next time you start it.